# How to make div slide right behind other?

Tags: jquery, menu

I need to make a menu, when a user hovers a link on the menu, which is a category subcategories div should slide right behind the menu. But the subcategories divs overlay the categories div. How to make them drop behind the menu?

html

```
<div class="categories3">
    <div class="parent3">
        <a href="http://test.app:8000/category/asperiores-impedit"> Asperiores impedit. <span class="caret-right"></span></a> 
        <div class="subcategory3">
            <a href="http://test.app:8000/category/illum-est"> Illum est. 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent3">
        <a href="http://test.app:8000/category/asperiores-impedit"> Asperiores impedit. <span class="caret-right"></span></a> 
        <div class="subcategory3">
            <a href="http://test.app:8000/category/illum-est"> Illum est. 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
 $('.parent3').hover(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     $(this).children('.subcategory3').animate({
        left: "100%"
    }, 300);

 }, function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     $(this).children('.subcategory3').animate({
        left: "0"
    }, 300 );      
 });
```

css

```
.categories3 {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #009688;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.subcategory3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #009688;
}

.parent3 a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.parent3 a:hover {
    background-color: #009688;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, elements that come later in the DOM show up "above" any before it if there is overlap.  You can override this by adjusting the z-index (CSS property) of the elements.  Give the ones you want "below" to have a lower z-index, and the ones you want "above" to have a higher number.

I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/to84v4qr/1/ with some additional minor CSS and JS changes to your code to try to make some visual sense of things.  But the salient changes are the following additions to the CSS:

```
.subcategory3{
  ...
  z-index: 1;
}
...
.parent3 a{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  ...
}
```

The `position: relative` on `.parent3 a` because z-index doesn't work on unpositioned elements (well, "static", the default).  `subcategory3` already had absolute positioning.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it overlays the right border of categories3, as it comes out. Can you tell me how to disable it? I want the border of categories3 to be in place as subcategories3 is coming out.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking. If it's that you want subcategory3's to appear to extend entirely outside of categories3, you'll have to make the "left" animation, the width of `div.parent a`, and the width of `.categories3` be the same length. I just shortened the first two to 50% for the fiddle because, otherwise, the subcategory3 submenus were animating off the visible page.

Comment: No, not that. When 'subcategories3' is sliding to the right it overlays the right border of 'category3', and it becomes white(in my case, because the background color is white'. When the animation is done, the right border appears on its place. Here is the screenshot
[link](http://s8.postimg.org/4n11aee1h/Screenshot_from_2015_09_04_23_57_58.png)

Comment: That screenshot is appearing very very tiny to me, haha. But I think I might better understand now from your explanation. You will probably have to make the categories3 border appear to be 1px (or whatever width its border is) wider than the .subcategories3 is allowed to extend out. You can probably accomplish this in some hackish way by putting something like `border-right: 1px solid transparent` on .subcategories3 or `margin-right: -1px` on .categories3.

Comment: Sorry about the screenshot, it seemed okay to me. Anyway, I wasn't able to fix it, can you give your contacts please where I can reach you? It is a tiny thing that drives me crazy, I need to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, this is already all beyond the scope of the original question (also, I'm not getting paid for it, hehe). I'll just say for now, play around with different widths for things likes borders, margins, padding, left, etc on the different elements, or maybe experiment with the right property instead of left (e.g. animate to "right: 1px")? You'll probably be able to better understand what's going on and figure out a workaround. Good luck.